# Flex ordering in column reverse

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following markup:

```css
.colReverse {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.border:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 60px auto 0px;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="colReverse border">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

On desktop, the `flex-direction` is `column`, so item, item, border. Which is How I want it (border always last).

On mobile, I'm changing the `flex-direction` to `column-reverse`, which obviously puts the border above the items.

Since I always want the border to be at the bottom, I've specified it's `order` to be 3rd (or last). However, this isn't working? Ideas why?

Comment: on column reverse you need to do the opposite, a negative value for example

Comment: A simple solution would be to make the pseudo absolute positioned, which will take it out of flow, and then give it `bottom: 0`. With that it doesn't matter which direction you use, it will always be at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Switching from `column` to `column-reverse` doesn't happen automatically. You need a trigger. The simplest solution is a media query.

So, just add a second rule to the media query that keeps your border in place on smaller screens.

```css
.colReverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.border::after {
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 60px auto 0px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
  .colReverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .border::after {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="colReverse border">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wcj2qkLy/)